# Please check my maths with respect to UK EU funding

Tags: european-union

I am attempting to determine whether Common External Tariff Customs duties are included in the widely circulated (in the UK) figure of around £8 billion net.

Using the sources listed below I have arrived at the following equation:

**EU Revenue from UK (2016, EUR, millions)**

```
VAT                                3314.9
GNI based own resource            15251.5
UK correction                     -5870.2
2014 Own Resources Decision          27.6
Lump sum reduction (DK, NL etc)     165.3
FSJ Adjustment (DK, IR, UK)          74.3
Traditional own resources          3161.1
Agricultural duties                   0
Sugar levies                         11.9
Customs duties                     3939.5
TOR collection costs               -790.3
Credits (regional devlpment etc)  -7051.6

Sum total                         12030.2 million EUR
                                  9022.65 billion GBP (approx, 1 EUR = 0.75 GBP)
```

This sum includes the rebate (“UK correction”) and total public and private sector EU credits to UK.

I have clearly either missed something, or made an error (eg double counting, or including something that is not normally included), because this value is much larger than the 8 billion figure

Where have I gone wrong?

Sources:

1. http://ec.europa.eu/budget/figures/interactive/index_en.cfm
2. For total public and private sector EU credits to UK: https://visual.ons.gov.uk/the-uk-contribution-to-the-eu-budget/

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but in the ONS article they link to where they get the data from: _"European Commission (EC) figures are from the data download in their financial report and have been converted into sterling using an average exchange rate each year for the years 2012 to 2016."_

Comment: Thank you. Can exchange rate account for this large of a gap between my expectation (approx 8bn GBP) and the calculated (12.5bn GBP)?

Comment: No, exchange rates at the time were about 0.75, giving £10.5bn

Comment: Another thought I had is that _maybe_ they defined the year differently, but they are actually both calendar year 2016

Comment: The rate I used for calculating the credits was 0.89. I will update it.

Comment: Just to note, my "about 0.75" was from a visual inspection of an exchange rate chart.

Comment: The combination of making the exchange rates more consistent and using the EUs figure for the amount of credits sent to the UK, gets us closer. I have no idea of the accuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are counting the EU’s *traditional own resources* twice, because they consist of customs duties and sugar levies, minus the collection costs that the UK may keep (20%).

According to your table, sugar levies (11.9) and customs duties (3939.5) add up to 3951.4. From that amount 20% are 790.3 – the “traditional own resources (TOR) collection costs”, which need to be subtracted because they don’t go to the EU. The difference is 3161.1, which is already in your table as the “traditional own resources”.